# How to make an inline tag <a> display inline after a block tag <p>?

Tags: html

I need help with HTML, I don't know how to do this. So I've got:

```
<p>Text text text Text text text Text text text Text text text Text text text Text text text Text text text Text text text Text text text <a href="#">Link</a></p>
```

So it will show:

> Text text text Text text text Text text text Text text text Text text
> text Text text text Text text text Text text text Text text text
> **Link**

How can I make this link be next to the text but not in the `<p>` tag?  Is it possible?

Comment: Place your anchor tag(`<a>`) inside your `<p>` tag. `<p> Text text .... <a>....</a></p>`

Comment: dude I've done it in example. I need that a would be outside p. But next to the text

Comment: if you can remove `p` and use `span` yes we can do it! or else , remove all style of `p` that is useless effort.. as it will become another `div` tag

Comment: `p {display:inline-block;}` ) although I would give the p a clas and style that rather than all `p`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `display:inline;` to your p tag like this:

```
p {
    display:inline;
}
```

Or if you don't want to change every `p` tag, then add a class and add the property to that like this:

```css
p.sameLine {display:inline;}
```

```html
<p class="sameLine">Text text text Text text text Text text text Text text text Text text text Text text text Text text text</p> <a href="#">Link</a>
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/65sf2f66/60/

Comment: And what if I need to set max-height? :)

Comment: @McLaren That is out of context with your original question but I think you will have to use float on the `p` as well as `a` tag to be able to add `min-height/max-height` properties to them.

Comment: @AndrewLyndem no need for float - just use inline-block to set a max height: http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/65sf2f66/63/

Comment: @Pete I checked your fiddle and adding a property like say, `min-height:50px;` did not changed the element's height to 50px. Also, what is the overflow property in your fiddle for? It's causing the anchor tag to look like it's floated to the left of a scrollable div.

Comment: min height works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/65sf2f66/64/.  The overflow in the other fiddle is just to show the max height works - otherwise it will just show the overflow, and to solve the alignment problem, just add vertical align property: http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/65sf2f66/66/ (you can't add a min-height larger than the max-height if you just added it to the last fiddle).  On this I have removed the overflow: http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/65sf2f66/68/ but you can see the max height is applied but the text spills out which is why you need the overflow

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```html
<p style="display:inline-block">paragraph</p>
<a href="#">anchor</a>
```

[More information on the display property](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/display)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one:

```
<p style="display:inline">Text text text Text text text Text text text Text text text Text text text Text text text Text text text Text text text Text text text </p> <a href="#">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try

```
<p>
    <span class="normal-text">Lots of Texts</span>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
</p>
```

in your HTML file and

```
.normal-text
{
    max-height: 50px;
}
```

in a corresponding .css file, then you will be able to apply css styling

- `<p>` to style everything in the paragraph, text and link included
- `.normal-text` to style everything in the normal, non-linked text
- `<a>` to style everything to do with the link / anchor.

Please see http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-height.asp for information on max-height and a useful example.